# "Openness" of sets in $\tau$, where $\tau$ is generated by a basis $\mathcal{B}$

Tags: general-topology

I am learning topology by working through the book written by Munkres.

According to Munkres,

> $\mathcal{B}$ forms a basis on $X$ if:
>
> 1. $\forall x \in X, \exists B \in \mathcal{B} : x \in B$
> 2. $x \in B_1\cap B_2 \implies \exists B_3: x \in B_3 \subset B_1\cap B_2$
>
> Furthermore: $U$ is open in $X$ if $\forall x \in U, \exists B \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B \wedge B \subset U$.

The last part is where I become confused. The problem is that I cannot see how, for instance, this guarantees that $U$ is open in $X$. For a counterexample assume that $B = \overline{B}(x,r)$ is a closed ball in $X = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $U$ is closed in $X$, then $\forall x \in U \exists B \in \mathcal{B} : x \in B \wedge B \subset U$ is true if $U = B$, but $U$ is then closed.

Will you kindly explain how the definition guarantees that $U$ is open?

Comment: You claim is not true.

Comment: @TroyWoo That is great news, will you kindly explain what is wrong with it?

Comment: Just consider a boundary point $x$ of $U$, there are no $B$ that contains $x$ and is contained in $U$.

Comment: Depends on whether B is proper subset of U. In my example i let B = U

Comment: In that case, $U$ is an open set under your strange basis (not the same as the metric topology). Man, you need to forget about $\mathbb R$ a little bit to learn new stuffs.

Comment: What is the definition of strange basis? I do not understand.

Comment: For $\mathcal{B}$ to be a basis (of the topology), the first condition is that all elements of $\mathcal{B}$ are open. It seems you overlooked that condition.

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer, Munkres does not insist that the basis elements are open in $X$. It sounds like the fact that $\forall x\in U \exists x \in B\in \mathcal{B} : B \subseteq U$ guarantees the openness. However I cannot see that it does.

Comment: @MariusJonsson The union of an arbitrary number of basis elements is defined to be an open subset in the generated topology. In particular, $B$ is an open subset for $\forall B\in\mathcal B$.

Answer (score 2):

There is some context missing from Munkres book that would be helpful to give a good answer to this question. I do not have my copy of Munkres nearby, but I think I can guess what is going on.

You have quoted the definition of the statement "$\cal B$ is a basis on $X$":

> 1. $\forall x \in X, \exists B \in \mathcal{B} : x \in B$
> 2. $x \in B_1\cap B_2 \implies \exists B_3: x \in B_3 \subset B_1\cap B_2$

Notice that this definition does not mention open sets and it does not mention a topology. The only precondition here is that $X$ is a set. What is being defined here is just the concept of a *basis on a set*.

Next you have quoted the definition of "$U$ is open in $X$":

> $\forall x \in U, \exists B \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B \wedge B \subset U$

The concept being defined here can be expressed in several different ways. One way is that this is the definition of *open sets relative to the basis $\cal B$"*. Another way is that this is the definition of the *topology $\tau$ generated by the basis $\cal B$*, namely
$$\tau = \{U \mid \forall x \in U, \exists B \in \mathcal{B} \quad\text{such that} \quad x \in B \quad \text{and} \quad B \subset U\}
$$
I wish I could better remember Munkres terminology, I don't quite think he uses the terminology "topology generated by the basis $\mathcal B$". Anyway, notice again that the set $X$ has no further preconditions or structure other than the basis $\mathcal B$: there is no pre-given topology in this definition. The topology generated by $\mathcal B$ is being *defined*.

---

Once these concepts have been defined, one can then define another concept which is perhaps more centrally important for general application. Namely,

> Given a set $X$ and a topology $\tau$ on $X$, and given a collection of subsets $\mathcal B$ of $X$, we say that *$\mathcal B$ is a basis of the topology $\tau$* if $\mathcal B$ is a basis on $X$ and $\tau$ is the topology generated by $\mathcal B$.

Comment: He does use "topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$".

Comment: Okay, good, then I think that may confirm what is going on with this question.

Comment: Yes, that is what is going on indeed. He defines a "basis for a topology on $X$", and the topology generated by that basis. What he does not (at least there, haven't looked further yet) do is to explicitly say what a basis of a given topology is.

Comment: Yes, it occurred to me to address that final issue with my latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that one of the axioms of topology is that any union of open sets is open. We also have the following equality: $$U=\bigcup\{B\in\mathcal B\mid\exists x\in U: x\in B\land B\subseteq U\}.$$

So $U$ can be written as the union of open sets, and so it is open.

As for closed sets, consider the case of $\Bbb R$ and $\mathcal B$ is the set of open intervals with rational endpoints. Now take $\{0\}$ which is certainly closed. Does it include any open interval?